# Zalenium launches chrome browser but doesn't kicks off test

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, zalenium

I'm trying to run my test scripts on zalenium, though the browser gets launched(noticed in vnc) but the tests don't run on the container. I have noticed the below error in logs.

Selenium version:

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

Selenium Logs :

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities
>   [{name=TestCaseName, browserName=chrome, platform=LINUX}], required
>   capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>               Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'

Docker Logs :

> WARN  o.s.jetty9.server.HttpChannel - /wd/hub/session
>   java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException:
>   No capabilities found in request: {"capabilities":
>   {"desiredCapabilities":
>   {"name":"TestcaseName","browserName":"chrome","platform":"LINUX"},"requiredCapabilities":
>   {}}}

Comment: Are you passing all the required capabilities while creating the connection?

Comment: @ManiDeepak  **version: '3.0.1'** ? Why not v3.141.59?

Comment: @DebanjanB upgrading to v3.141.59 worked like a charm, Our base framework is desgined to work on v3.01 and now i updated my pom to 3.141.59. Can you please let me know why 3.141.59 worked and not below version. Tons of Thanks for the quick reply and solving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session.
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

It was evident from your *maven dependency* and the log messages that you are using *Selenium v3.0.1*

---

Factually, there is **no** concrete indication within either the *Selenium Logs* or the *Docker Logs* to identify any root cause of the issue sans the **`SessionNotCreatedException`**. In case of *SessionNotCreatedException* the primary suspect is always towards the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using and it is always advisable to update the following binaries:

- Selenium JARs (v3.141.59)
- ChromeDriver (v75.0)
- Chrome Browser (v75.0)